# How to skip empty strings with String.format on android?

Tags: android

Users of my app will be able to re-format the information they see - they will need to edit string like:

```
<b>Movie name:</b> %1$s, <br><b>Country: </b> %2$s.
```

Then I take this string and apply String.format.
For ex., Country is empty, in result user will see:

> **Movie name**: SomeMovieName, Country:

Is there any way to not show the whole Country line if %2$s is empty?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes `<br><b>Country: </b>` needs to be included in the replacement string "Country" rather than in the final formated string.

Comment: Then user will not be able to change the formatting (to make it italic for ex., instead of bold).

Comment: An easy way is to break the long string into smaller strings which user can edit in a form with multiple fields. The other way I can think of is to create some markers so that computer knows which blocks to remove like <country>...</country> tags which should be removed before final render.